# ShareLatex beginner

Tags: errors

The common message says: missing control sequence inserted

```
\resheading{Education}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{itemize}
\item\ressubheading{completed high school with excellent grades}{Larisa, Greece}{}{2005}




\item \ressubheading{Aristotle University of Thessaloniki}{Thessaloniki, Greece}{Ptyxion-BSc in Physics Department degree note 7.18 out of 10}{2005 - 2011}
\item \ressubheading{Chalmers University of Technology}{Gothenburg, Sweden}{MSc in Nanotechnology}{2013 - 2015}


  \item \ressubheading{University of Gothenburg} {Gothenburg, Sweden}{Erasmus program}{January 2009 - June 2010}
  \item\ressubheading{Nanotechnology Basics}{Online Course by Coursera}{Rice University}{2013}
  \item \ressubheading{Nanomechamical characterization for materials in Energy}{Webinar Series}{by Elsevier Ltd.}{2011}
  \item \ressubheading{Force Curve and Force Volume Analysis}{Webinar}{by Image Metrology}{2011}
  \end{itemize}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX! I'm afraid your question is difficult to answer as it stands. A control sequence is any command starting with a backslash, e.g. `\item`, and the error means that you have one in your document is not defined by the document class or the packages you have loaded. It could be that you have misspelt one, e.g. `\itme` instead of `\item`. As you haven't reported the whole error, we cannot say more at the moment. The error will tell you which command is the problem, and the line it is on. (ctd.)

Comment: If you can report the entire error message, and create a complete, yet minimal example (starting with `\documentclass` ending with `\end{document}`, a so called [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)) we can give more specific advice.